# Generate a row for each month using a range of dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have the following code, which generates a row for the first of the month. As you can see I have the number of months hardcoded (200). How can I modify the code to remove the hardcoded value (200) and replace it with an end date (ie 04.30.2023). Where this will generate the last row as APR 2023.

```
WITH
  test_data
  AS
   (SELECT TO_DATE ('01.03.2008', 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS mnth FROM DUAL),
  mnth_data (mnth, max_mnth)
  AS
   (SELECT mnth, ADD_MONTHS (mnth, 200) AS max_mnth FROM test_data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ADD_MONTHS (mnth, 1) AS mnth, max_mnth
     FROM mnth_data
    WHERE mnth < max_mnth)
SELECT mnth
 FROM mnth_data
```

Comment: End date of what? Replace `add_months(..., 200)` with your end date calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the end date into your query:

```sql
WITH test_data (month, end_month) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2008-03-01', DATE '2023-04-30' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(month, 1), end_month
  FROM   test_data
  WHERE  ADD_MONTHS(month, 1) <= end_month
)
SELECT month
FROM   test_data
```

or, if you want to generate dates up until the current month then:

```sql
WITH test_data (month, end_month) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2008-03-01', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(month, 1), end_month
  FROM   test_data
  WHERE  ADD_MONTHS(month, 1) < end_month
)
SELECT month
FROM   test_data;
```

Which both output:

| MONTH |
| --- |
| 2008-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 2008-04-01 00:00:00 |
| 2008-05-01 00:00:00 |
| ... |
| 2023-02-01 00:00:00 |
| 2023-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 2023-04-01 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dHH3n82C)